# vscode jumps to a specific volume afer reopen in container

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

I have a nice project with a .devcontainer config. Since the vscode update to 1.63 I have some trouble with the docker setup. Now I'm using the newest 1.64.0

I just want to build a new container with a clean volume an start in a fresh environment.

What happens is, that a new container is starting and I see some stuff from another container.
Same if I clone a git repo into a container volume.

1. Why are some containers connected with the same volume for the workspace?
2. Why do I fall back every time to the same volume?

In the devcontainer.json I set:

```
"workspaceFolder": "/workspace",
"workspaceMount": "source=remote-workspace,target=/workspace,type=volume",
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To build a new devcontainer in a fresh environment you can install [devcotainer cli](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/devcontainer-cli) and trigger build manually.

I'm used to mount workspace as bind mount (on windows with wsl2 files) insted of volume mount, i think that the main issue is the volume name: if both project has "source=remote-workspace" the volume will be detected as the same.

With nodejs where I want to keep `node_modules` folder inside container, I have done a double mount following this [official vscode guide for this usecase](https://code.visualstudio.com/remote/advancedcontainers/improve-performance#_use-a-targeted-named-volume).

So I have left workspaceMount as a default bindmount than I have added a volue that override a specific folder.

```json
{
  "mounts": [
    //      vvvvvvvvvvv name must be unique
    "source=projectname-node_modules,target=${containerWorkspaceFolder}/node_modules,type=volume"
  ]
}
```

The results is:

- every file `/` is server by container
- but all inside `${containerWorkspaceFolder}` is served by bind mount
- but all inside `${containerWorkspaceFolder}/node_modules` is server by named volumes

Comment: thanks for your answer. I'm a little bit under fire now. Maybe I have a question after a deeper look. Please stay tuned ;)